# make datalist or listview appear like grid

Tags: asp.net, listview, grid, datalist

How can I make datalist or listview items to be listed as grid not a single vertical column?
What I want is the items of the list to appear as a grid not one item below the other. I have a list of employees' photos that I read from a database, and I want to put them in a grid so I will utilise the empty space and reduce scrolling in the page, [exactly the way Amazon does it in this page](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_172282_ln?rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Atv&keywords=tv&ie=UTF8&qid=1335589545&scn=172282&h=9c8869a5594999512c172f8eb18ce8e3e3ac62e9). How can I configure the list to appear as grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `RepeatColumn` attribute to `2` or more.

Answer (score 0):

```
#mygrid li {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create like follow:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
<table border="0" cellpadding="1">
<tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE">
<th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkId" runat="server">Id</asp:LinkButton></th>
<th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server">Name</asp:LinkButton></th>
<th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkType" runat="server">Type</asp:LinkButton></th>
```

<%#Eval("ID") %>
   
   <%#Eval("FirstName")+""+Eval("LastName") %>
   <%#Eval("ContactType") %>
   
  


  
   <%#Eval("ID") %>
   <%#Eval("FirstName")+" "+
    Eval("LastName") %>
   <%#Eval("ContactType") %>